# Verify that a method was called using Mockito without specifying arguments

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

Using Mockito, is it possible to verify that a function was called/not called using a spy or a mock, without giving the actual arguments?  For example if I have a class or object:

```
class MyClass{
  def f(x : Int) = x
}

object MyObject{
  def f(x : Int) = x
}
```

I want to be able to say something like:

```
val my_class = mock[MyClass]
// Do something that causes method f of MyClass to be called
there was one(my_class).f // Doesn't give arguments

val my_object = spy(MyObject)
// Do something that causes method f of MyObject to be called
there was one(my_object).f // Doesn't give arguments
```

I just want to verify that the method was called, not that it received specific arguments. Also, when I am checking that a function was not called:

```
there was no(my_object).f
```

I don't want to verify that it was not called with certain arguments, but that it was not called at all.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [Mockito matchers](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html) to specify that you want to verify that the call was made for any argument.

in your case that would be

```
there was one (my_object/my_class).f(any[Int])
```